# Getting the Nonce for an Account

Tags: nonce, offline

I know of three ways to get the nonce for an account.

- MyEtherWallet under the Offline Transactions tab.
- At the command line with Geth
- Manually count the number of outgoing transactions for an account using Etherscan. Oddly, Etherscan counts the number of transactions for an account and displays this value on the account page but does not display the number of outgoing transactions (the nonce).

My question is: does anyone know of any other quick methods of getting the nonce for an account?

Thanks, John

Comment: To the answer of the duplicated question, I added an option of using a service like Infura.  (Marking this a duplicate so that 1 place for the answer; feel free to add your own answers.)

Comment: Thanks eth. That's I was hoping for some website like etherscan that I could go to and put in the account number an get the nonce back. MyEtherWallet is the only thing I found like that so far. Still this a good technique that I can put in my bag of tricks. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
```

if you want to compose raw transactions, the field looks like this:

```
nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address))
```

[API reference](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactioncount)

Comment: Is there a way to get it using `ethers` instead?